# MVC 4 persist search on next page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a View Form which include SearchModel and result as well.

Here below is my search model.

```
public class UserViewModel
        {
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Search { get; set; }
            public string SortBy { get; set; }
            public string SortOrder { get; set; }
            public IPagedList<Users> Users{ get; set; }
        }
     public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel filter, int? page)
            {
        filter.Users=GetUsersFromDatabase().ToList();
            }

         public ActionResult ToggleActive(bool IsActive, Guid Id)
        {
// Set update operation to user
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = Request["page"]  });
        }
```

Now I want to redirect user on ToggleActive based on UserViewModel filter values on listing page. I hope you get my point.

How to pass the search only model. Please let me know the easy way.

In my view I have created the view.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ToggleActive", "User", new { IsActive = item.IsActive, Id = item.UserID, page = ViewData["CurrentPage"]})">
                                            Active/Deactive
                                        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view has defined the model:

```
@model UserViewModel
```

Send your current model back to the controller's ToggleActive action:

```
public ActionResult ToggleActive(bool IsActive, Guid Id, int page, UserViewModel filter)
{
    // Do stuff with the filter
    // Set update operation to user
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = Request["page"]  });
}
```

And change your action url to include the model:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ToggleActive", "User", new { IsActive = item.IsActive, Id = item.UserID, page = ViewData["CurrentPage"], filter = Model})">
                                            Active/Deactive
                                        </a>
```

Comment: Is it right to pass the Model directly to the action url because the Model is already contains  public IPagedList<Users> Users{ get; set; }

Comment: The link looks like http://domain/User/ToggleActive/1001?IsActive=True&page=1&filter=MySchool.Models.UserViewModel and inside toggle function filter is null.